# Installing APK from SD card (problem with FileProvider)

Tags: android, apk, android-fileprovider

I have a problem with a file provider. I have successfully downloaded an apk to my phone. The apk is either stored on SD or internal phone storage.

```
(SD Card)
/storage/3565-6665/Android/data/com.mytest/files/My App Name/Download/app-v1.3.apk

(internal storage)
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mytest/files/My App Name/Download/app-v1.3.apk
```

The problem is that from internal storage the file is found and can be installed but on the SD card it does not work and throws folling exception:

> Failed to find configured root that contains
> /storage/3565-6665/Android/data/com.mytest/files/My App
> Name/Download/app-v1.3.apk

My path.xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." /></paths>
```

And the `FileProvider` in the manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/path" />
</provider>
```

And I'm installing the apk in the following way:

```
File file = my_file;
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file); //for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 24
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
    fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplication(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
}
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri);
promptInstall.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
promptInstall.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
promptInstall.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileProvider` does not support removable storage. Either:

- Always download to what you call "internal storage" (but from the Android SDK standpoint is [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html))
- Have the user choose the APK on removable storage using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, and use the `Uri` you get from that for your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`
- Create your own `ContentProvider` that can serve files from your app's removable storage directories, then use that `ContentProvider` instead of `FileProvider` for your `Uri`
- Switch to using `PackageInstaller`, as this bypasses the need for any sort of `ContentProvider`, and it addresses the fact that using `ACTION_VIEW` for app installation is deprecated on Android 10+

Comment: I think using PackageInstaller is probably the best solution. Could you please provide an example how I can use it in my code? I have searched for it but it is not that clear to me.

Comment: @machinery: [This Kotlin sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/AppInstaller) (covered in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Q)) demonstrates the basic steps.